# Use .find() for removing an element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have an array, and I want to delete a specific element, through `.find()`. How should I use it for such purpose?
I know that it should have a condition, let's say

```
if(element === selectedItem)
{
   Array.splice(index,1);
}
```

but i do not know how to include this into `.find()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing items from an `Array` is not `find()`'s purpose.

What you want is `Array.filter()`.

From [MDN Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Here's an example:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var evenNumbers = numbers.filter(number => {
  // returning something that evaluates to `true` will
  // keep the item in the result Array
  return number % 2 === 0
})

console.log(evenNumbers)
```

### Protip:

Don't instinctively try to composite the Array helper functions you already know into something that does what you want.

Instead, read the [MDN Array docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), specifically the 'Methods' section from the sidebar, which already contains a lot of useful methods.

Comment: however filter will not remove from the original array (as the OP want) and will return another array.

Comment: True - However I'd argue it's better to [avoid mutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) where possible.

Comment: Agree, but that's all the question actually standing on

Comment: There's no but - it's an answer that doesn't directly answer the question but still achieves the OP's purpose. Downvote if you don't agree and move on.

Comment: Ii tried `.filter()` but i had some issues with it, that's why i asked about find :)

Comment: @Eugen-AndreiColiban Solve the issues of `filter()` instead of going for a more verbose and unnecessary approach, which is what you went with. Apart from that, the `index` approach you are going with cannot be easily composited/chained later on. Having implementation issues with a better solution is not an "excuse" to go with a worse solution.

Comment: @Eugen-AndreiColiban This is why you should [ask about your actual problem, not the supposed solution](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use findIndex instead of find:

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Betty' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Mark' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Elizabeth' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Samuel' }    
];

var index = data.findIndex(x => x.name === 'Mark');
if (index >= 0)
    data.splice(index, 1);
    
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a condition `function`, like:

```
function condition(element) {
    return element === selectedItem;
}
```

Now, you can use find to find the value of the element like this:

```
var myItem = myArray.find(condition);
```

And then

```
myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(myItem), 1);
```

However, if your array might have multiple matches to remove, then

```
var myItem;
while ((myItem = myArray.find(condition)) !== undefined) {
    myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(myItem), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the index, you need `indexOf` and not `find`, so that you can perform further operations on top of that.

Comment: There is a method `find()` which returns first element that satisfies the condition given. May be he needs that.

Comment: well, may be, but then he needs index of the element after that. well, that can be combined to `findIndex`

Comment: @Madhavan.V but as the OP posted `element === selectedItem` it seems like direct reference compare and should work with `indexOf`